# Operator semigroups (lecture notes)

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Can you recommend good lecture notes (or a book) about this topic? Basically I would like something which covers more or less the first chapter of the book "Markov Processes" by Ethier and Kurtz, but hopefully written more like lecture notes (a bit more verbose and more examples, ideally with connections to probability) and less like in a reference book. I would prefer if it were available online, but it is not strictly necessary. Thanks!

A side question - generally my knowledge of functional analysis is rather lacking and I would probably benefit a lot from improving it. Can you recommend a good book which goes more or less from the basics (I had an introductory functional analysis lecture some years ago, but I could revisit that again and then move on). I am mostly concerned about those parts of functional analysis that have connections to stochastic processes, but I think I generally need a good basic overview (a bit less rudimentary than the one I have now). Again, I prefer verbose style to reference book style, lecture notes that are seriously meant to be read from cover to cover would be ideal.

Comment: It is not what you asked but Kosaku Yosida's *Functional Analysis* is right here by my side and I wouldn't change it for other source to learn about operator semigroups.

Comment: @Pp..: A friend of mine is also a fan of Yosida. Could you elaborate on it's special features? *(Like what really nice things it does...)*

Comment: Pp..: Thanks, I will check it out.